# Opening multiple Matplotlib figures in multiple windows instead of tabs on macOS

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I want to create multiple figure with Matplotlib in python, using the macosx backend. Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(9, 3))
#Sets ticks, the title, and the x and y values
make_plot(data)
plt.figure(2, figsize=(5, 3))
make_plot(other_data)
plt.show()
```

This creates a single window, with two tabs. One for figure 1, and one for figure 2. I want both figures to open in different windows instead of tabs.
How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
Here's a minimal code sample:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)

f1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,x**2)

f2 = plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x,x**2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Cool. Matplotlib does not provide tabs by default. So you are using a program that does this for you. Maybe you want to share which one that is, so people have a clou on what's going on.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it's just a python script, launched from the terminal, rendering on the macosx backend. I assume the addition of tabs came with macOS Sierra which added an implementation for tabs for free with the system

Comment: I use Jupyter so My answer was based on an educated guess.  I will delete it if it’s not needed ...

Comment: Have you tried making two calls to `plt.show()`, one after each `plt.plot()`?

Comment: What happens if you use a different backend (`import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")`)?

Comment: @WilliamMiller I have. This shows the first plot and blocks the whole script until that's closed. Only after that it shows the next

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Same thing

Comment: It's surprising for me that any matplotlib backend would add tabs; although there had been some [feature request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2194) and some [work on adding this for gtk](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2465), this has never been truely implemented. I am still convinced that what you see is not produced by matplotlib, but some other program. Maybe adding a screen-shot would help itentify what we're dealing with here?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the way I understand is, that the system defaults to new tabs instead of windows (actually, it's a setting), but applications can override that setting. Seems like none of the backends override it (or give the option to override it)

Comment: You might have more luck asking your question on [Ask Different (Apple)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), in the context of whether or not it's possible to disable tabbing for individual applications.